# Vert.x. Execute multiple inserts in a single call to update()

Tags: java, sql, asynchronous, vert.x

Is it possible to execute multiple SQL insertions/updates using Vert.x JDBCClient object?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Vert.x 3.3 you will have batching support available so you can do batch updates as:

```
List<String> batch = new ArrayList<>();
batch.add("INSERT INTO emp (NAME) VALUES ('JOE')");
batch.add("INSERT INTO emp (NAME) VALUES ('JANE')");

connection.batch(batch, res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    List<Integer> result = res.result();
  } else {
    // Failed!
  }
});
```

Or if you want to reuse a prepared statement:

```
List<JsonArray> batch = new ArrayList<>();
batch.add(new JsonArray().add("joe"));
batch.add(new JsonArray().add("jane"));

connection.batchWithParams("INSERT INTO emp (name) VALUES (?)", batch, res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    List<Integer> result = res.result();
  } else {
    // Failed!
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! i read about this feature in 3.3. but what about present editions? Can i concatenate my sql-queries in a sigle String and execute them in a single call?

Comment: It depends on your jdbc driver, for example that will work for postgres but i've not tried for any other dbms

Comment: @PauloLopes Batch insert is blocking the event thread. I ve tried placing the batch insert code inside executeBlocking method too. However, am getting the same exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a reproducer and submit a bug? It's hard to tell what is going on without seeing the code.

Comment: @PauloLopes, How can we write batch query with SQLClient in 4.x